# What is wrong in this xmonad configuration?

Tags: xmonad, haskell

I have the following configuration on xmonad.hs, I really just want to add xmobar to the spawn pipe, but i dont know whats wrong. This is my config:

```
import XMonad

main = do
    xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar &"
    xmonad $ defaultConfig
        { modMask = mod4Mask -- Use Super instead of Alt
        , terminal = "xterm -fg white -bg black"
        -- more changes
        }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
xmonad.hs:6:9: parse error on input `{'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to do this and you can see that [in my xmonad config](https://bitbucket.org/robertmassaioli/robertmassaioli-xmonad/src/68464c715042/xmonad.hs?at=master). Essentially the important lines are these ones:

```
-- put it all together
main = do
    nScreens <- countScreens    -- just in case you are on a laptop like me count the screens so that you can go
    xmonad =<< xmobar myBaseConfig
      { modMask = myModMask
```

That xmonad there is provided [by this line here](https://bitbucket.org/robertmassaioli/robertmassaioli-xmonad/src/68464c715042/xmonad.hs?at=master#cl-38):

```
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog (dynamicLogXinerama, xmobar)
```

You can see the [documentation for the xmobar function here](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#v:xmobar).

And using that you should be able to do this for yourself! Cheers. You may also be able to pick up some other tips from my XMonad config so I would suggest that you have a browse.